# GraphSharp BalloonTreeLayout pins all vertices in one place

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, graph-sharp

I am working on Graph# and need to use BalloonTreeLayout, but the result is the layout groups all vertices in one place together.

My code is :

```
<Sample:MyGraphLayout x:Name="layout"
                      LayoutAlgorithmType="BalloonTree"
                      OverlapRemovalAlgorithmType="FSA"
                      Graph="{Binding}"
                      AsyncCompute="true"
                      ShowAllStates="false"
                      HighlightAlgorithmType="Simple">
</Sample:MyGraphLayout>
```

How to do with Graph# to make to this result?[Balloon Tree Layout in a commerical product](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-diagram-gallery-automatic-layouts-balloon-tree-layout.aspx)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have create a dummy graph sample project and i can share it for you.
Following features are implemented: double click on vertex, find vertex by id, sample indicator boxes on vertex, context menu (remove vertex, recursive function - show all joined vertices only), labeled edges. Sorry for my english ;)
[image]